# Performance penalty for accessing properties in base class (C#)

Tags: c#, performance, linq, properties

I was profiling my class library and optimizing things, when I've noticed this strange issue:

There's a base class, and I have other classes, derived from it.
Base class has a public property.
I'm doing Linq queries that involve this property elsewhere in the code.

Now, doing 100,000 iterations (not even a million) I can see that if I also add a property with the same name to the derived class (intellisense highlights it with a tooltip "This property hides inherited member"), thus making basically a 'Shortcut' (but also a duplication of the property) - Code runs significantly faster... to me 350 ms. over an iteration of 100,000 is quite significant.

Why is it, please ? :) What can be done ?

---

More details:

Base class:

```
public abstract class ContentItem: IContent
{
    internal ContentItem() { }

    [DataMember]
    [IndexedField(true, false)]
    public string Guid { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [IndexedField(false, true)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Derived "POCO":

```
[IndexedClass]
public class Channel : ContentItem, IContent
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    [ContentField]
    public string TitleShort { get; set; }
}
```

Repository class (doing the linq queries): (Generic repository)

```
public virtual T ByTitle(string title)
{
    return All.Find(item => item.Title == title);
}
```

Where `All` is a `List<Channel>` and has 2700 items.

Code for testing:

```
private static void test(Content.Repository<Content.Channel> channels)
        {
            int iterations = 100000;

            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
            {
                var channel = channels.ByTitle("Unique-Title");
            }

            watch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("Done in {0} ms.", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
```

Comment: Can you please share code to reproduce this, as well as the code you used for benchmarking?

Comment: yep, brb, leaving office, going home

Comment: code you used for benchmarking

Comment: And, what is the total time? 350 ms by itself does mot say much.

Comment: total time is about 1.7 seconds. 350 ms. is the difference (performance gain) of adding a duplicate property into the derived class

Comment: @DenisVolovik It's 20%. That's weird, because I've just tested it and get 5-10% performance difference.

Comment: I'm failing to see how 350ms is "significant".  If you have code like this that is executing say 10 million iterations, then we are still only talking about a 35 second difference.  Not exactly earth shattering and certainly at a level where many other factors would cause greater performance issues.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I suspect a difference in bitness, or NETFX version (including possibly the workstation/server versions of mscorlib, on old enough NETFX)

Comment: I just tested the code and i have no difference in speed at all. Find(item => item.Title == title); and Find(item => item.ShortTitle == title); 4 ms arithmetic mean of difs.

Comment: @Dmitry - not ShortTitle.. but .Title in derived class...

Comment: @DenisVolovik the is no difference in `ShrotTitle` in your code and `public new string Title`

Comment: I wasn't adding "new"... I added property Title as is (now let's say, it's sitting next to the .ShortTitle)

Comment: @DenisVolovik there is no difference in adding property and adding the `new` keyword except for warning message

Comment: ok well, there's still that difference in performance that I see, anyhow now it seems it's all due to the virtual/non virtual call and I should basically accept it as it is.. ?

Comment: @DenisVolovik the difference in peformance is not in virtual/non virtual call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you examine the generated IL, when your code is using the derived class' local property, it's generating a `call` rather than a `callvirt`, which is just plain cheaper.

This seems like a premature optimization unless you're in a time critical loop.

Worrying about the difference between `call` and `callvirt` performance when building iteration using linq seems.... particularly premature.

Comment: What do you mean by 'premature', please? You mean I should not worry about it at this stage? But I'm preparing a class library (an 'engine' of a cms, so why not make it perfect?)

Comment: Define "perfect" in a technically meaningful manner. Is your system's performance at loads for which you intend it to handle sufficient with `callvirt`? Is changing your object model so that you have to have local members to call in a LINQ query a sufficient improvement in performance compared to the cost to the quality of your codebase? If you can't point to a spec or defect that says it's not fast enough... maybe worrying about `callvirt` vs. `call` isn't anything more than a curiosity at this stage.

Comment: well yes, it's a performance vs. code quality I guess in this particular case. The CMS is not intended to handle work with more than 50,000 or even close to 100,000 objects. (be it 'Articles', or 'Products', etc) but there is code, for example that checks if a Duplicate title exists already or not.. it's executed on each "Save" of object... It's not a problem when you have 2,000 items.. well... 350ms won't be a big problem for 100,000 items either I guess :) (if you ever manage to reach that capacity)

Comment: a CMS with 100k active items is getting into the realm of "large". I suspect other places would start to creak and show signs of scaling issues before this does.

Comment: Yes, ok, I guess that I'm a freak, but must accept this "call" vs "callvirt", that's it (no big deal) :)

Comment: I'm also going to use reflection (with cached Get/Set accessors via a compiled Expression tree) to serialize/deserialize items to a Lucene index... so to me some stuff in here is 'time-critical' after all.

Comment: how often is the reindexing going to be done with that, though - once on save to the index?

Comment: saving one item is pretty fast.. it'll go to 'global index' and content type specific index... but I've yet to test de-serializing 100,000 items from lucene to the in-memory collection, etc... (hell, not sure why I would need it though) - the CMS is database-less...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38809/discussion-between-tetsujin-no-oni-and-denis-volovik)

Answer (score 3):

When you're hiding the property you're making it a non-virtual call, rather than a virtual call to a member.  Virtual dispatch does have a certain cost associated with it, which is why you're able to declare non-virtual properties/methods.

That said, in most applications the costs associated with a virtual method/property are not a problem at all.  There is a difference, yes, but it's not much at all in the context of most programs.

Comment: It's always amusing to see how two answerers both expressed the same thing at the same time, in different language.

Comment: They're complimentary to me, both describing the virtual call... :)

Answer (score 0):

The difference in call and callvirt is really small.

I simplified your code. Please run it and tell us what answer do you have.
I have no difference in using both properties.

```
public abstract class ContentItem 
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string AnotherTitle { get; set; }
}

public class Channel : ContentItem
{
    public string AnotherTitle { get; set; }
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var channels = new List<Channel>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
    {
        channels.Add(new Channel(){Title = i.ToString(), AnotherTitle = i.ToString()});
    }
    int iterations = 100000;
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch;
    var difs = new List<int>();
    int rounds = 10;
    for (int k = 0; k < rounds ; k++)
    {
        watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            var channel = channels.Find(item => item.Title == "2345");
        }
        watch.Stop();
        long timerValue = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            var channel = channels.Find(item => item.AnotherTitle == "2345");
        }
        watch.Stop();
        difs.Add((int)(timerValue - watch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
    }

    Console.WriteLine("result middle dif " + difs.Sum()/rounds);
}
```

---

Update

Also in this case you do not have any `call` methods in IL.
both `Title` and `AnotherTitle` look like

```
IL_0008:  callvirt   instance string ConsoleApplication4.Program/ContentItem::get_Title()
IL_0016:  callvirt   instance string ConsoleApplication4.Program/Channel::get_AnotherTitle()
```

The problem you have has nothing to do with `call` or `callvirt`. Probably the difference is in code, that you don't show to us.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'm rather surprised that the get_AnotherTitle is compiling as a callvirt rather than call. (It's been a while since I was looking at this in relation to the need for never-put-virtual-calls-in-constructors advice)

Comment: Result: original code = "middle dif 5"..
Then I removed "AnotherTitle" from class "Channel" (now it only sits in the base class), and result is dif -61...